# Postgres - How to Dynamically generate User and Password

Tags: postgresql

I would like to choose a password manager to generate postgres users and passwords on demand with limited TTL.  In addition I would like this password manager to have high-availability (cluster of 3?).  I prefer this utility to be opensource and free.

If you are using one and having good experience, I would appreciate getting your recommendation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Kerberos or LDAP authentication and manage your password there. That allows you to enforce fancy rules on passwords. The only downside is that you have to write something that keeps the PostgreSQL users synchronized with the users in the identity management system.

With passwords stored in the database, you cannot have password expiration (which is considered bad security anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.  What are the differences of using Kerberos or LDAP vs. Hashicorp vault.  The latter seems to automatically handle password rotation and creation of users etc.

Comment: The difference is that I never heard of Hashicorp vault.